# Delete row from db using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, web

Problem is in that when I am clicking on button **DELETE** in userNotes.jsp test function in deleteData - `out.println(value)`, works - it shows me the current value of what was clicked on the button but nothing else. It does not delete data from the db, and does not send a redirect on response, what do I need to do? 
**userNotes.jsp**

```
                        <table id="notes" border="2">
                            <tr>

                                <td>note name</td>
                                <td>note</td>

                            </tr>
                            <%
                                PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                                int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("r"));
                                try {
                                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evernoteDB",
                                            "evernoteDB", "0633739768z");

                                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs;
                                    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM note");

                                    while (rs.next())
                                    {
                            %>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
                                <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
                                <td>

                                            <a href=deleteData?id=<%=rs.getString(1) %>> Delete </a>

                                </td>
                       </tr>
                            <%

                                    }
                                    rs.close();
                                    st.close();
                                    con.close();
                                }
                                catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
                                {
                                    writer.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                                catch(SQLException e)
                                {
                                    writer.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    writer.println(e);
                                }

                            %>
                        </table>
```

**deleteData - servlet**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;


@WebServlet("/deleteData")
public class deleteData extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    String value = request.getParameter("id");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evernoteDB",
                "evernoteDB", "0633739768z");


        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM note WHERE noteName=" + value);
        out.print(value);
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/userNotes.jsp");

        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep your business logic in Java classes/EJBs and only use JSPs for the view layer

Comment: technically, you can do this and we can even fix the problem with the above code. However, In principal, it does NOT sound right to me to access to DB from a JSP. DB operations should **NOT** be implemented on webpages as they belong to server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `noteName` is of type `String`, so your execute query should quote the value.

```
st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM note WHERE noteName='" + value + "'");
```

Consider using a `PreparedStatement` instead. It's secure and takes care of such errors too.

And since you're redirecting, you shouldn't be trying to a set any content headers. Remove the following as the servlet isn't supposed to write any response but redirect instead.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

Also, don't hardcode the host and port number like that or you won't be able to deploy your generated *war* on a different server. Use a relative URL with `sendRedirect()` like

```
conn.close();
response.sendRedirect("/userNotes.jsp");
return;
```